# Defining the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im trying to solve this exercise:
Define the directional derivative of a function f(x,y) at point (a,b) in direction (u,v). Prove a formula for this derivative.

Im kinda lost, I dont really have much knowledge in directional derivatives and I dont understand the question itself. With define they want me to give a definition, and then it looks like they want me to prove this definition? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context?  If this from a certain textbook?  If it's from a class (and you're not sure what it is your supposed to do in the question), you should probably just ask the professor what he's looking for.

Comment: Its from a class, but I really dont have the possibility to ask our professor this week. Since im working from home.

Comment: You can't email the professor?

Comment: I could probably try to do that, but im not sure if he'll answer in time..

Comment: He answered me with "You will have to interpret it yourself."
Im honestly lost...

Comment: Show it's the dot product with the gradient! That's what he means... maybe

Comment: Umm okay..But isnt the formulating kinda weird "Prove a formula for this derivative" ?.
So the derivative is the definition of the directional derivative, and "prove a formula" sounds like he wants a new formula?

Comment: Right, so the new formula is 
$$
D_{(u,v)} = u \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) + v \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)
$$

Comment: Okay yeah, so I am going to prove that this formula equals to the defintion of the directional derivative?

Comment: That's what I *think* he's asking for.  I don't really know what else he could mean.

Comment: I'v been trying to prove that the new formula equals to the definition, without any succes. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The directional derivative of a function $f(x,y)$ in the direction $(u,v)$ at $(a,b)$ is usally defined by
$$
D_{(u,v)}f(a,b) := \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+hu,b+hv)-f(a,b)}{h}.
$$
You can find more on this topic [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I managed to find this formula. But im still stuck at "Prove a formula for this derivative".

Comment: As we are all, probably. A definition cannot be "proved". You can only prove its consistency with some other definitions.

Comment: Im lost. I emailed my professor and he answered with "You will have to interpret it yourself".
I'v been looking at this exercise for hours now, but cant seem to "interpret" it correctly...I think I should give up ;/